# Read First column of xlsx file create Txt files than Put second column data to corresonding txt file

Tags: python, xlsx, txt

I have xlsx file estimated 20000 rows and 2 columns for example ;

```
station feedback
1   aax2a3x9564
1   a52a42x366x
1   29a9a756022
1   a6645207742
2   a7692202650
2   a64399x05a6
2   a9909a2x470
2   32654440a54
4   a9306aa7244
4   2a9a303342x
4   a66a52054xx
9   424272a64x0
9   aa4733a3a60
10  4225034a090
10  a9a29054x32
```

i want to use the first column (station) as Txt File names and second column (feedback) as data?

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried and what specific problem you have difficulty with?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` and `openpyxl` to do that with no pain:

```
# Python env: pip install pandas openpyxl
# Anaconda env: conda install pandas openpyxl
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
for station, data in df.groupby('station'):
    with open(f'{station}.txt', 'w') as fp:
        fp.writelines('\n'.join(data['feedback'].tolist()))
```

Content of `1.txt`:

```
aax2a3x9564
a52a42x366x
29a9a756022
a6645207742
```

Content of `2.txt`:

```
a7692202650
a64399x05a6
a9909a2x470
32654440a54
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern and help my solution
    df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
    for station, data in df.groupby('alan'):
        with open(f'{station}.txt', 'w') as fp:
            for item in data['kimlik']:
                fp.write("%s\n" % item)